# looking to add an apple to my snake game as a moving object

Tags: c#, console-application

I have created a snake-like game using c# and the command prompt, but now i am stuck when it comes to adding an apple for the snake to chase. As in once it gets put on screen it does not stay in the bounds of the grid. I am also looking to add a random variable so that once it has been hit it will move to a different location.

```
static void Apple()
{
    do
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        NewApple = RandApple.Next(200);
        Console.Write("L");
    } while (!Gameover);
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code. What is the purpose of the loop?

Comment: What do you need?
To print on screen an apple, then random its location. 
But i have not figured out how to properly implement it.

Comment: Try Console.SetCursorPos(NewApple, 0) before Console.Write

Answer (score 0):

This requires a number of different things to be in place. First of all, you need some way to identify the bounds of your playing area.

After that, you need to use this along with a Random.Next generator on both X and Y coordinates to get a position for the apple. Then do a Console.SetCursorPosition providing X and Y as Left and Top respectively, and then Console.Write the apple's "model" (Not WriteLine. This will completely mess up your playing field, I can assure you). Once you got that settled, you need to move it all into a method you're only going to call once the snake actually encounters the apple.

You might also want to make sure that it does not spawn on top of anywhere the snake is currently at.

And if I understand you correctly, you're making a new Thread/Task per object in your game (Snake head, body, Apple, Bonus objects, etc.). This is a bad idea, considering you want to keep everything synchronized, so that you wont run into situations where one task is moving the console cursor, while another task is writing. (We're only talking fractions of seconds here where such things can happen, but that is the speed at which the computer works. So it can, and will happen).

All in all, never use multiple threads to handle the same parts of your code.

Let me know if this makes sense. I will try to explain deeper, if needed.

Comment: You see that's where i am having trouble, i have my grid set in a different call method but only have a loop set for the Y values as it would not use the x loop properly. 
I did have a Random.Next generator trying to add the apple in but it wouldn't execute properly.

No i don't have a separate Task per object, I have one main for my KeyPress function but nearly everything i use is in that.

Comment: Sounds like you got some things right. For example, yes, you should have your loop method calling a bunch of separate methods, which in turn might call even more methods. It needs to be built sort of like a hierarchy.
Without some more code, I cant tell why the X looping wont work. In regards to the problem with accessing a grid, pass it down into the method as a parameter. If necessary make a class that contains the grid. Remember, Structs are VALUES being copied, Classes are REFERENCES being (as the name implies) references. Difference being that editing classes in methods, edits the content

Comment: static void DrawGrid(){
    Console.SetCursorPosition(28, 20);
    Console.Write("Press any key to start");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.Clear();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 5);
    Console.WriteLine("---");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 35);
    Console.WriteLine("---");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 11);
    for (int y = 0; y < 29; y++)
    {
    row = y + 6;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(8, row);
    Console.WriteLine(" |");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(70, row);
    Console.WriteLine("|"); 
    row++;
    }
    }

Comment: That is the code i used to draw the grid, but its not coming out properly here

Answer (score 0):

This is not an efficient way but could help you continue with your work.

Loop forever and can get 2 random numbers using Random Class, then check if the board is empty and also the snake isn't there:

```
    while(true)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int row = rand.Next(0, N_ROWS); //Where N_ROWS is the board's number of rows
        int col = rand.Next(0, N_COLS); //Where N_COLS is the board's number of cols 
        if(Board[row,col] == EMPTY && Board[row,col] != SNAKE_BODY) //assuming your board is a 2D array
        {
             Board[row,col] = Apple;  //Place the apple
             break;
        }
     }
```

EDIT: Forgot to break, sorry

Comment: I do not know the amount of columns that are in my program. Is there anyway to check the amount?

Comment: Either use the Console.Width/Height (I think that's the name), or decide a specific width and height, and resize the console window to that size.

Comment: If I remember right, the snake game was had a squared board...
Either way, I think you should decide the size, and not re-size the console window but rather draw the board with boarders.